# PHP: No match when using exclamation mark in regular expression

Tags: php, regex, escaping, no-match

I'm trying to use preg_match to find a commented part in a loaded HTML file. The exclamation mark present seems to break it, however. Whenever I try to use

```
preg_match("/<!/", "<!", $matches);
```

an empty $matches[0] is returned. I've tried

```
preg_match("/< !/", "< !", $matches);
preg_match("/!</", "!<", $matches);
```

and these do return "< !" and "!<". I've searched everywhere for a solution, but I can't seem to find a solution for this most likely very easy-to-solve problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: Works fine in CLI. However, you should _always_ escape the escape symbol, if you don't want it's escaping behaviour `\\\`

Comment: Very odd. I wonder what could be it. That was actually a typo. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure an empty `$matches[0]` is returned, or is it just that `$matches[0]` is itself an HTML comment that gets hidden? Try `var_dump($matches)` and check the length of the string.

Comment: Same thing. This is returned:
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "

Comment: See, the length is 2. What's happening is that `<!` is seen as the start of an HTML tag, and so is not shown in the browser. If you do `echo htmlspecialchars($matches[0]);` you will very clearly see `<!`. You would also see `<!` if you viewed the source of the page.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I apologise for my stupidity. Haha. Thank you very much.